# Array_rand no duplicate then you refresh page

Tags: php, arrays

How to do `array_rand` with no duplicates then you refresh page?

What I mean is when your form submit, this question is deleted, when refresh the page it's not seen.

```
 if($action == "first")
    {
        $arrQuote = array();
        $arrQuote[0] = '    
                <form method="post" action="index.php?action=second" class="form-inline">
                    <h2>Ar var yra geras dalykas</h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="klausimas_1">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit_1" class="btn btn-default">Add Task</button>
                </form>     >';
        $arrQuote[1] = '
                <form method="post" action="index.php?action=second" class="form-inline">
                    <h2>Ar int yra geras dalykas</h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="klausimas_2">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit_2" class="btn btn-default">Add Task</button>
                </form>             ';
        echo $arrQuote[array_rand($arrQuote)];  
    }
```

Comment: Huh. What now? And why is that all in italic. Could you please try explaining the situation a bit better, what you expect to happen, what real results are happening that you don't like. Its really confusing from what you've provided.

Comment: Are you just trying to choose a random array entry?

Comment: Yes, but when you submit for example "submit_2" destroy this form and no dublicate for next form with array_rand

Comment: Without some kind of persistence, (session, etc.) Every request is completely independent from any other request. There's no way to no what was previously given if you don't keep track of it somehow.

Comment: It's called `array_rand` because it is *random*. If you don't maintain state with a cookie or something, there's no way to know what the previous result was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a session to persist across pages.  You only want to define `$_SESSION['arrQuote']` in the *first* form and add it to the session.  You can then get and remove one element on this page and the *second* page etc:

```
session_start();
//$_SESSION['arrQuote'][0] = ..........
//$_SESSION['arrQuote'][1] = ..........
$key = array_rand($_SESSION['arrQuote']);
echo $_SESSION['arrQuote'][$key];
unset($_SESSION['arrQuote'][$key]);
```

However, shuffle and remove would be easier:

```
session_start();
//$_SESSION['arrQuote'][0] = ..........
//$_SESSION['arrQuote'][1] = ..........
shuffle($_SESSION['arrQuote']);
echo array_pop($_SESSION['arrQuote']);
```